# Как добавить строку с тегами html

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру есть строка:

```
let text = `some text <b>is</b> here`

const target = $(`#targ`) // h1

target.html(text)
```

Получится:

```
console.log(target) // some text is here
```

Мне нужно чтоб было так, чтобы с тегами пушилось:

```
console.log(target) // `some text <b>is</b> here`
```

Comment: `console.log(target)` выведет информацию о jQuery-объекте. Вы точно именно так пишете? `console.log(target.html())` выведет требуемое значение.

Comment: Всем спасибо за быстрый отклик, разобрался, просто затупил очень :(

Comment: Если не хотите приводить вопрос в порядок и расписывать в ответе что и как вы исправили, то просто удалите вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let text = 'some text <b>is</b> here';

$('#targ1').html(text);
$('#targ2').text(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="targ1"></span>
<br/>
<span id="targ2"></span>
```

Comment: Сорян, не правильно написал, что б <b> применилось

Comment: @Anton опишите в вопросе подробно что вы хотите сделать, без непонятных "пушилось".

Comment: @Regent Мой код недостаточно пушистый. Огорчен.

Comment: @Anton Вам нужно, чтобы в консоль выводился декорированый текст? Зачем?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = 'some text <b>is</b> here',
    target = $('#targ');

target.html(text);

console.log(target.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targ"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="targ"></p>
<script>
    let text = 'some text <b>is</b> here';    
    document.getElementById('targ').innerText = text;        
</script>
```